# Running a command in a Docker container with variables

Tags: bash, docker, exec

I am using a docker-compose type of scenario.  I would like to back up the database for partkeepr on a nightly basis.  I can get a bash shell by doing a `docker exec -it docker-partkeer_database_1 bash` into the container and run the `mysqldump` command just fine but I can't run it successfully as a `docker exec` type of function.

I run `docker exec -it docker-partkeepr_database_1 bash -c mysqldump --databases partkeepr -upartkeepr -pUSERPASSWORD  > /var/lib/mysql/backup/partkeeprsql.$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql`.

That date part on the end works just fine when I already have gotten in with a bash shell in the container but not outside of it. I can run the command as written without the date part just fine but I need the date so I can have multiple backups.

The system errors with `-bash: /var/lib/mysql/backup/partkeeprsql.$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql: No such file or directory`.

Have any ideas?

Comment: What operating system are you using on the host? What do you get if you just run `date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S` on the host? Note that anything after the `>` is NOT ran inside the container, it's ran on the host, so in order for it to run properly `date` has to be a working command on the host machine, not just the container

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer to my question. I didn't wrap the command after the bash -c in ""'s.  Once I ran the command below it worked like a charm. I just wanted everyone to know the answer that I figured out.

docker exec -it docker-partkeepr_database_1 bash -c "mysqldump --databases partkeepr -upartkeepr -
pUSERPASSWORD  > /var/lib/mysql/backup/partkeeprsql.$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql"